# if (isset($_POST["submit"]) and $_POST["chargeathome"]== "Yes")

Tags: php, session, post

I have a problem with my code, can you please help me? What I want to do in the first place is to ask the user if he has charging possibility at home. If his answer is yes, I want to run a file (homechargingyes.php) with the charging options he has and I want to save his answers in session variables. If his answer is no, another file will run (homechargingno.php) and only a message will be visible. 
Here are my files with the code:

main file:

```
Do you have any charging possibility at household?</br>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="chargeathome" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="chargeathome" value="No">No
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) and $_POST["chargeathome"]== "Yes"){
        include 'homechargingyes.php';
}elseif (isset($_POST["submit"]) and $_POST["chargeathome"]== "No" ){
        include 'homechargingno.php';
}
?>
```

homechargingyes.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <b>Type of socket:</b><input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="Domestic socket 120V">Domestic socket 120V</br>
    <input name="typeofsockethome" type="radio" value="Domestic socket 240V">Domestic socket 240V</br>
    <input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="CEE Blue">CEE Blue</br>
    <input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="CEE Red">CEE Red</br>
    <input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="Wallbox">Wallbox</br>
    <b>Hours of continuous battery charge:</b> <input name="charginghourshome" type="number" min="0" max="24" value=""></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php
$_SESSION["chargeathome"]= $_POST["chargeathome"];
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"]= $_POST["typeofsockethome"];
    $_SESSION["charginghourshome"]= $_POST["charginghourshome"];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And homechargingno.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$_SESSION["chargeathome"]= $_POST["chargeathome"];
echo "There is no charging possibility at home.";
?>
```

If the user clicks the "No" button everything is ok. But if he checks "Yes", right after pressing submit there is a notice: Undefined index: typeofsockethome in homechargingyes.php on line 21  and another one Undefined index: charginghourshome in homechargingyes.php on line 22. If I ignore these notices and choose one of the option above and click submit other notices about undefined indexes appear. This time is about the variable "chargeathome" in my main file. 
Can you understand what is wrong and help me?

Comment: ` $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"]= $_POST["typeofsockethome"];
    $_SESSION["charginghourshome"]= $_POST["charginghourshome"];`
you are posting only one value `chargeathome`  on page where these two come from

Comment: K `typeofsockethome` this is not defined how you can access it

Comment: That error messages (notices) are pretty clear, it contains names of indexes which doesn't exist, line where you're trying to access them. What more information do you need?

Comment: BTW you should never expect, that anything coming from user (e.g. `GET`, `POST` etc.) will always be there. So whenever you read from there, check if it exists first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the name of submit from `homechargingyes.php`

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit">
```

and cahnge this

```
if (isset($_POST["submit1"])){
    $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"]= $_POST["typeofsockethome"];
    $_SESSION["charginghourshome"]= $_POST["charginghourshome"];
}
```

this will resolve your issue

**Note:**

because you already have clicked on submit of `main.php` which is
 `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>` when it include `homechargingyes.php` page it checks for `$_POST['submit']` which is already posted in $_POST array

Comment: Thank you Junaid! Can I ask you something else? If I want to use $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"] in another subpage (result.php) which is linked with the main file, what should I do? I thought that saving this as session variable would be ok but I can't access it from the result.php

Comment: you can access it from result.php if you store this value as session but i thing for reminder you have to use `session_start()` at top of the page

Comment: my result.php file is like this: if ($_SESSION["chargeathome"]== "Yes"){
echo "Type of socket at home:".$_SESSION["typeofsockethome"]."<br>";
echo "Hours of continuous battery charge at home:".$_SESSION["charginghourshome"]."<br>";
}else{
echo "no";
}

Comment: and I have used session_start(); at the top of the page. To be more specefic, it prins the "yes" or "no" answer and the Type of socket at home: and Hours of continuous battery charge at home: but there are no values next to them.

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION)`; what is result of this

Comment: it is like it has never written the $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"] and $_SESSION["charginghourshome"]

Comment: this is because on page `homechargingyes.php` you have to select `typeofsockethome` and `charginghourshome` and press submit after this it will store in session and can be use in result.php

Comment: if you could show me your code online i will resolve your issue

Comment: no I still have the problem. Every other session variables I pass from other subpages work fine. That doesn't happen with these 2. I select the options I want and then I press submit but these values don't appear in the result.php

Comment: and give me url after saving this is online code editor

Comment: this is the url for the homechargingyes.php https://eval.in/426858. i think the problem is that the varaibles $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"] and $_SESSION["charginghourshome"] are not saved in a way that can be accessed from the result.php file which is linked with the main file and not with the homechargingyes.php

Comment: when i try to print these values in the result.php there are notices Undefined index: typeofsockethome and Undefined index: charginghourshome. But I can see the value of $_SESSION["chargeathome"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I condensed your code and placed everything all on one page.

Part of the problem before was having multiple forms showing on the page and each one asking if the submit button had been clicked ie: $_POST['submit']

No need for separate pages and includes.

This also includes the results.php question you asked Junaid about.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php if (!isset($_POST["update"])) { // if the form has never been submitted ?>
Do you have any charging possibility at household?</br>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="chargeathome" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="chargeathome" value="No">No
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="form1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php }
if (isset($_POST["update"]) && ($_POST["update"] == "form1") && $_POST['chargeathome'] == 'Yes'){
    $_SESSION["chargeathome"] = "Yes";
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<b>Type of socket:</b><input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="Domestic socket 120V">Domestic socket 120V</br>
<input name="typeofsockethome" type="radio" value="Domestic socket 240V">Domestic socket 240V</br>
<input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="CEE Blue">CEE Blue</br>
<input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="CEE Red">CEE Red</br>
<input type="radio" name="typeofsockethome" value="Wallbox">Wallbox</br>
<b>Hours of continuous battery charge:</b> <input name="charginghourshome" type="number" min="0" max="24" value=""></br>
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="form2">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php }
if (isset($_POST["update"]) && $_POST['update'] == 'form2'){
    $_SESSION["typeofsockethome"]= $_POST["typeofsockethome"];
    $_SESSION["charginghourshome"]= $_POST["charginghourshome"];
?>
You do have charging ability at home<br><br>
Your socket type is: <?php echo $_SESSION['typeofsockethome'] ?><br><br>
Your charging time is: <?php echo $_SESSION['charginghourshome'] ?><br><br>
<?php }
if(isset($_POST["update"]) && $_POST["chargeathome"] == "No" ){
    $_SESSION["chargeathome"] = $_POST["chargeathome"];
?>
There is no charging possibility at home
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

Hope this helps